# 13.10 Saucy login issues; black screen, loop, and freeze

Tags: nvidia, upgrade, login, 13.10

Once upgraded to 13.10 I was not able to get past the login screen. I had the black screen.
Also; I can not log on with low graphics mode from recovery either. It makes no difference if I try default graphics driver or not.

Then after running

> sudo install -f

from recovery root prompt I got a login loop.

I have purged fglrx, fglrx-legacy, and nvidia-current. I updated my repository with xorg-edgers and reinstalled nvidia-current. Now it semi-freezes at the login screen when I try to log on as my normal user.  I say 'semi' because I can still use my mouse to click on the upper right hand Ubuntu logo and Shut Down or Restart the PC.

I still cannot log on with my user name, but I can through the Guest login.  While logged in as Guest I added a new user account with administrative privileges.  I CAN log into this account without problem and from here am able to see that my .dmrc file in my original account reads:

> [Desktop] Session=XBMC

I have changed 'Session=XBMC' to 'Session=ubuntu' and rebooted, but to no avail.  The file resets itself and makes a backup of my changes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 0):

> Solved by clean install.

Originally found in the top of the question...

Comment: I don't really think this is a good solution. OF course a clean install would solve most problems as long as they are not HW related. I've been experiencing the same issue and have been playing around a bit trying to resolve it, to no avail, however I would not like to do a fresh install and having to set everything up again. If I ever do solve the problem I will be sure to post the answer here.

Comment: @boywithaxe I only posted this answer so other users could see what solution the OP went with. I didn't come up with the solution it was found in the question, I just wanted to clarify what solution the OP went with.